# Reading my child pipe created by exec() with C

Tags: c, exec, fork, pipe

I'm just starting to learn C programming and I have some uncertainty about `fork()`, `exec()`, `pipe()`, etc.

I've developed this code, but when I execute it, the variable `c` remains empty, so I don't know if the child isn't writing to the pipe, or the parent isn't reading from it.

Could you help me please? This is the code:

```
int main() {
int pid=0;
int pipefd[2];
char* c=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));   
FILE *fp;

pipe(pipefd);

pid=fork();

if (pid==0){
    close(pipefd[0]);
    dup2(pipefd[1],1);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    execl("ls -l | cut -c28","ls -l | cut -c28", (char *) 0);
}
else{

    close(pipefd[1]);
    read(pipefd[0], c, 1);
    char* path="/home/random";
    char* txt=".txt";
    char* root=malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(txt) + sizeof(char));
    strcpy(root,path);
    strcat(root,c);
    strcat(root,txt);
    close(pipefd[0]);

    fp=fopen(root,"w+");
    (...)
}
```

The problem is that the final root string its only `"/home/random.txt"` because there is nothing in the char `c`, and what I want is to open the file `"/home/random(number stored in char c).txt"`.

Comment: Check that your `execl` call isn't returning - I don't think you can call `execl` like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execl` executes a single command, and is not aware of shell concepts such as pipes. If you want to execute a shell command, you will have to execute a shell, as follows:

```
execl("/bin/sh","/bin/sh","-c","ls -l | cut -c28", (char*) 0);
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the NULL `argv[0]` - I don't think that's allowed either.

Comment: He did pass an `argv[0]`, the same as the program name.

Answer (score 1):

***Always*** check the return value of the system calls (like [`execve(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) and derived functions like [`execl(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/execl.3.html)), and use the [`errno(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) to figure out what went wrong.

In your case the `execl` line fails.

Answer (score 0):

Using strcpy/strcat seems a bit excessively complex. snprintf can turn those 3 lines into one.

```
snprintf( root, size_of_buf, "/home/random%s", c );
```

Additionally, check your error codes. As noted, execl is failing and you don't know it. fork, dup2, ...,can also fail, you want to know sooner rather than later.